# Displaying pair plot in Pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, plot

I am trying to display a pair plot by creating from scatter_matrix in pandas dataframe. This is how the pair plot is created:

```
# Create dataframe from data in X_train
# Label the columns using the strings in iris_dataset.feature_names
iris_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(X_train, columns=iris_dataset.feature_names)
# Create a scatter matrix from the dataframe, color by y_train
grr = pd.scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe, c=y_train, figsize=(15, 15), marker='o',
hist_kwds={'bins': 20}, s=60, alpha=.8, cmap=mglearn.cm3)
```

I want to display the pair plot to look something like this;

[image]

I am using Python v3.6 and [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm) and am not using Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This code worked for me using Python 3.5.2:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

from sklearn import datasets

iris_dataset = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris_dataset.data
Y = iris_dataset.target

iris_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=iris_dataset.feature_names)

# Create a scatter matrix from the dataframe, color by y_train
grr = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe, c=Y, figsize=(15, 15), marker='o',
                                 hist_kwds={'bins': 20}, s=60, alpha=.8)
```

For pandas version < v0.20.0.

Thanks to [michael-szczepaniak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45195783/3027854) for pointing out that this API had been deprecated.

```
grr = pd.scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe, c=Y, figsize=(15, 15), marker='o',
                        hist_kwds={'bins': 20}, s=60, alpha=.8)
```

I just had to remove the `cmap=mglearn.cm3` piece, because I was not able to make mglearn work. There is a version mismatch issue with sklearn.

To not display the image and save it directly to file you can use this method:

```
plt.savefig('foo.png')
```

Also remove

```
# %matplotlib inline
```

[image]

Comment: your answer is correct if I am using Jupyter. However, I am using pycharm. `%matplotlib inline` doesn't run in my environment. Is it possible if I can plot the charts without using Jupyter? Thanks.

Comment: @user3848207 use `plt.savefig('foo.png')` to save the figure to file and not display inline.

Comment: Thanks. `plt.savefig('foo.png')` works. `plt.show()` works well for me too.

Comment: YvetteColomb: Thanks for pointing that out. Versions of softwares keep changing, so we need a good way for Stackoverflow to handle these issues. Having a standard way to deal with this will help everyone. Thanks to @Michael Szczepaniak for pointing the version mismatch issue :) and thanks to you for raising the discussion :)

Answer (score 16):

Just an update to Vikash's excellent answer.  The last two lines should now be:

```
grr = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe, c=Y, figsize=(15, 15), marker='o',
                                 hist_kwds={'bins': 20}, s=60, alpha=.8)
```

The **scatter_matrix** function has been moved to the **plotting** package, so the original answer, while correct is now deprecated.

So the complete code would now be:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

from sklearn import datasets

iris_dataset = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris_dataset.data
Y = iris_dataset.target

iris_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=iris_dataset.feature_names)
# create a scatter matrix from the dataframe, color by y_train
grr = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe, c=Y, figsize=(15, 15), marker='o',
                                 hist_kwds={'bins': 20}, s=60, alpha=.8)
```

Comment: The original answer no longer includes this, as per this meta post https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359441/1873567

Comment: Well, the original answer now re-includes this, as Vikash Singh did the right thing and updated his answer. So now this answer is completely redundant, again.

Answer (score 16):

This is also possible using [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/scatterplot_matrix.html):

```
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset("iris")
sns.pairplot(df, hue="species")
```

[image: Seaborn pairplot of iris data]

Answer (score 1):

I finally know how to do it with PyCharm.

Just import `matploblib.plotting` as `plt` instead:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import mglearn
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

iris_dataset = load_iris()

X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(iris_dataset['data'],iris_dataset['target'],random_state=0)
iris_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(X_train,columns=iris_dataset.feature_names)

grr = scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe,c = Y_train,figsize = (15,15),marker = 'o',
                        hist_kwds={'bins':20},s=60,alpha=.8,cmap = mglearn.cm3)
plt.show()
```

Then it works perfect as below:

[image: Plot image]

Comment: How does this add value to existing answers?

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett  some code is not useful at this moment,so I just post a version of correct code

Comment: What does this mean: "just import matploblib.plotting as plt instead."

Answer (score 1):

[image]first of all use 
**`pip install mglearn`**
then import the mglearn

the code will be like this...

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import mglearn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(X_train,columns=iris_dataset.feature_names)
grr=pd.scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe,
                  c=y_train,figsize=(15,15),marker='o',hist_kwds={'bins':20},
                  s=60,alpha=.8,cmap=mglearn.cm3)
plt.show()
```