# Matplotlib to plot a pairplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Yesterday I posted this:
[Correlation scatter plot using DataFrame matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56178621/correlation-scatter-plot-using-dataframe-matrix?noredirect=1#comment98989413_56178621)

Because my English is not so good on the technical side, it was hard for me to explain what was my problem.

I'm trying to be able to plot a **pairplot** using this correlation data:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJvG1.png

```
ozone,radiation,temperature,wind,
1.0,0.3483416929936026,0.6985414096486389,-0.6129507522144628
0.3483416929936026,1.0,0.2940876437245132,-0.12736562398818144
0.6985414096486389,0.2940876437245132,1.0,-0.49714591092004284
-0.6129507522144628,-0.12736562398818144,-0.49714591092004284,1.0
```

I tried with pandas but I had poor results, plus I'd prefer to plot it with matplotlib if necessary. I've been trying to find solutions online for this question but I haven't been successful. Please help!

Comment: Your correlation data is short, please post it in the question as text instead of an image.  Also, can you define what you mean by a `pair plot`? I don't know what that is.

Comment: Pair plot : get the scatterplot for each 2-combination of variables of your dataframe. See the R documentation [here](https://statistical-programming.com/r-pairs-plot-example/)

Comment: @Hoog Edited, with pair plot I mean something like this:
https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*zX-EcizVkcXcwYNq4d-8RA.png

Comment: Seaborn is built on top of matplotlib, so you could look into Seaborn's [pairplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) function.

Comment: @HS-nebula I've seen this, but I'd like to find a solution purely using matplotlib

Comment: Then maybe [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42592493/displaying-pair-plot-in-pandas-data-frame) will help?

Comment: @HS-nebula Not sure how to replicate this answer using my correlated data

Comment: In the example, alpha is the transparency of the plotted data. You can see that it is set to 0.8, a float. Make sure you have this correct. Also, in the answer, `Y` is a list (or numpy array) of 3 numbers, the classes of the subjects. Might also work as pandas Series (column of dataframe). You could also omit the coloring, `c=Y` if you don't have any categories for your subjects. The second answer also adds an update for recent versions of Pandas, if you haven't already seen that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on the link in my comment, you can do

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'ozone': [1.0, 0.3483416929936026, 0.6985414096486389, -0.6129507522144628],
               'radiation': [0.3483416929936026, 1.0, 0.2940876437245132, -0.12736562398818144],
               'temperature':[0.6985414096486389, 0.2940876437245132, 1.0, -0.49714591092004284],
               'wind': [-0.6129507522144628, -0.12736562398818144, -0.49714591092004284, 1.0]})

g = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(df, figsize=(10,10), marker = 'o', hist_kwds = {'bins': 10}, s = 60, alpha = 0.8)

plt.show()
```

[image]
I'm not sure why you don't want to use Seaborn, but you can do the same thing easily by doing

```
# Plot using Seaborn
sns.pairplot(df, diag_kws={'bins': 10})
```

[image]

Comment: This was the same result I was getting, this is correct. I wasn't understanding my own result!